# Are there any digital cameras that support a preview for a panorama crop while shooting?

Tags: panorama

I'd like to force myself to shoot panoramic (2:1 or greater) shots occasionally. It would be nice if I could do this in camera. I'd prefer it to be RAW. It could be as simple as frame lines in the viewfinder.

I don't need the camera to do the actual cropping, but if it could apply the crop in metadata to the raw file, that would be nice (Similar to the digital zoom on the Lecia Q's). I just want to force the panoramic perspective when shooting. Basically just adding black bars or framelines to the top and bottom of the image in viewfinder.

The main point is that the viewfinder shows the panoramic field of view for composition.

Similar to what the medium format FujiFilm GFX50R will do. https://fujilove.com/shooting-panoramas-with-the-gfx-50r/

Comment: My first thought... Couldn't you MacGyver together a mask and just tape it to your LCD screen?

Comment: I could, but that seems cumbersome.

Comment: I believe the APS-C film cameras generally did this.  I don't have mine any more to check.

Comment: @RossMillikan they did. I remember having an aps-c point n shoot in the late 90's that would do this. It would cover part of the viewfinder. I remember it being one of it's touted features. Really it was just somehow letting the lab know to crop before printing. I don't think it actually covered any part of the film when shooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom [Magic Lantern](https://magiclantern.fm/) firmware for [older Canon EOS camera's](https://builds.magiclantern.fm/index.html) has a [cropmarks feature](https://wiki.magiclantern.fm/userguide#cropmarks) that allows you to store custom overlays.
The [source code](https://foss.heptapod.net/magic-lantern/magic-lantern/-/tree/branch/unified/data/cropmks) provides a few example cropmarks, these can be used as a starting point when creating custom cropmarks. There are also [YouTube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtBviFAn6rk) available on how to create these cropmarks.

Comment: something like that is exactly what I was talking about

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that by "panorama crop" you mean something like a 16:9 aspect ratio.

The answer to that is that many standalone digital cameras have a way, in the settings, to set another aspect ratio than that of the sensor, and that will cause the preview to be cropped to that aspect ratio. I do not use that feature, so I am not sure what happens in the final image, whether you can still get the missing parts from the raw file.

It is certainly a standard feature on Canon mirrorless cameras (I checked two models that I have, M50 and R7). One way to find cameras that have this feature may be [this comparison](https://geizhals.eu/?cat=dcamsp) (sorry, site is in German, I don't know of an English-language equivalent); if after "Auflösungen" (= resolutions) it lists different aspect ratios, I think that should mean that the camera has such a feature. There is also a [similar comparison for non-interchangeable-lens cameras](https://geizhals.at/?cat=dcam&pg=4#productlist).

Comment: The feature on the m50 is what I want, but 16:9 isn't panoramic. Generally anything 2:1 or greater would be. The Fujifilm GFX50R does this https://fujilove.com/shooting-panoramas-with-the-gfx-50r/ . I haven't heard of anyone doing this in less than medium format though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the article you referenced, the GFX 50R maintains the complete 4:3 sensor image in its RAW file while saving the jpeg in the cropped panoramic format. I don’t know of any camera which does not save the entire sensor image in its RAW format. One of the points of RAW is to obtain the image data from the entire sensor without the camera’s software applying formatting. A true panoramic camera would have a panoramic format sensor, as most true panoramic film cameras did.

Comment: saving the entire image is desired, it's the just the cropped preview in the viewfinder that I would like. Mostly for composing.